# stuck at defining static pointer and using it

Tags: c++, pointers

I stuck at defining a static pointer inside one of my class which is pointing to another class
here is the schema of what I've done :

```
#busineslogic.h
class BussinesLogic {

private :
static Samenamespace::otherclass_DataLogic::clsDL *DL;
 };

#busineslogic.cpp
 samenamespace {
 businessnamespace{
 clsBL{

   Samenamespace::businessnamespace::clsBL *Samenamespace::businessnamespace::clsBL::DL;
  }
 }
}
```

so with above definition I'll get error every time I compile the code , I've tried several other ways to overcome this problem but the face of the errors gonna change not the whole problem.

I want to know how can I access to another class from my class in such a static way I mean something like above example , how should I change my code ? or should add something extra?

Comment: @austin powers: You can edit your post and use the "Code Sample" button to format the source properly. Use preview to check if it looks the way it should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// header:
#include <other/b.hpp>

namespace example {
struct A {
  static other::B* name;
};
}


// implementation: (.cpp)
namespace example {
other::B* A::name;
}
```

*Edit:* With the cleanup of the question, it looks like B and A are in the same namespace, which would simplify the example:

```
// header:
#include <example/b.hpp>

namespace example {
struct A {
  static B* name;
};
}


// implementation: (.cpp)
namespace example {
B* A::name;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer , thats the exact point which I've been stucking on for two hours . 
I have another question I've came from C# and c++ isn't my main programming language but I know the basic aspect of c++ could you please tell me if I want to learn c++ in a way to not cope with above problem which book or source is suitable for me?
shall I start from scratch? or is there any shortcut available?
regards.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking there.  There are several good C++ books, such as Accelerated C++ (http://www.acceleratedcpp.com/).